# Where are d:DataContext d:DesignWidth... defined?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

There are some "special" namespaces mapped to prefixes like **d:** **mc:** ...

I would like to know where are the classes that handle attributes like `d:DesignWidth`, `d:DesignHeight`, `mc:Ignorable` and such.

They seem to like well known directives, but I don't know how the XAML parser deals with them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mc:Ignorable` will tell the XAML parser to ignore any errors that occur from the specified namespace. This is not defined anywhere. It's just an instruction for the parser.

`d:DesignWidth` and `d:DesignHeight` are the same. They don't exist. There's no class that manages them. They are instructions for the designer. When you open Blend or Visual Studio Designer, they interpret the values and apply `Width` and `Height` to the associated element.

Since `d:DesignWidth` and `d:DesignHeight` don't exist, they will throw an exception at runtime. BUT, `mc:Ignorable="d"` will absorb these exceptions and the parser keeps parsing.

Answer (score 1):

These are the namespace you are looking for

xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"

And a reading material for you 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/aa350024(v=vs.100).aspx